# How can I prevent tests from running during deploy?

Tags: java, maven

currently I have surefire configured though Spring Boot's BOM.

I have tests running during deploy though there seems to be some issue with one of them... that said this same test passes just fine in the previous part of the pipeline. I don't actually need these tests to run twice.

I would like to do this as part of my parent BOM (has springs BOM as its parent)

How can I configure tests to not be run during the deploy phase? `mvn deploy`, running `mvn test` and `mvn verify` must continue to work as normal.

Comment: Just to make sure: Is the 'previous parts of the pipeline' the exact same environment as the one you are deploying to? If they are, it might be ok to disable the tests. Always be weary though.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this while building(install) the archive itself. 
We can skip tests while building by two ways:
Using CLI:

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Make the same change in pom.xml as:

```
<configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</configuration>
```

Then give:

```
mvn install
```

Both will build the archive without running the testcases.

And mvn deploy, running mvn test and mvn verify will continue to work as normal. Since this command is independent of these three commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using commands while deploying or in pom.xml
To skip the entire unit test, uses argument `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

> OR in pom.xml

```
<configuration>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to configure in skipTests in surfire plugin

```
<configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
```

For more details please follow

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html